# Font does not load from aws s3 (400 bad request)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

I have a font in AWS s3. I want to load it into my Django website.
I am using `django-storages` to communicate to `AWS S3` 
Here is how I am loading

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: caviar;
        src: url({% static 'webfonts/fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf' %});
    }
</style>
```

I am getting 400 bad request error.

My Bucket policies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

ERROR:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>
Query-string authentication version 4 requires the X-Amz-Algorithm, X- 
Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, and 
X-Amz-Expires parameters.
</Message>
<RequestId>CA8F49CC58B9B9D1</RequestId>
 <HostId> xxxx08=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Can you access the response body of the failed request?  `Bad Request` has several unrelated causes but the actual error is in the response.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, updated with error. Please kindly check.

Comment: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Comment: @error404, can you please tell me what should I look in that link?